# Install app on windows phone 8 without sd card

Tags: windows-phone-8

Ok, when ever I search for this phrase I get tons of links on how to use the SD card to install an app, I don't have an SD card, is there another way of installing an app from a XAP file?

Answer (score 5):

As of now its not possible. if you download the xap to any other memory than SD card, you'll have to first move it to SD Card and then install it from there. Read through this official blog post for more details - http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/12/13/windows-phone-store-expands-adds-new-features.aspx

here's what is quoted from the website -

> The web Store also now has support for installing apps via SD card,
>   which many Windows Phone 8 models support. This option can be useful
>   when a cellular or Wi-Fi data connection isn’t available. Just look
>   for the “Download and install manually” link on the app’s details
>   page. Click to download the app’s installation—or.xap—file, which can
>   then be copied over to the phone’s SD card and installed. (See How do
>   I install apps from an SD card? for step-by-step instructions.)

To install any xap from SD Card, read this blog post - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-US/How-to/wp8/apps/how-do-i-install-apps-from-an-sd-card

Comment: Hi we have developed an app but how can we install the .cab or xap file on some other windows phone directly?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar You can follow the above steps if your phones support SD cards. If not, you'll need to install the app via Application Deployment tool - provided your phone is developer unlocked. http://windowsphonehub.in/tutorials/deploy-xap-using-application-deployment-tool-windows-phone-8/. If you have a Windows Phone Developer account, you can dev unlock your phone following this - http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/39391/windows-phone-8-unlock-devices-for-development/

Answer (score 4):

If your phone is developer unlocked, you can use the Application Deployment tool supplied with the Windows Phone SDK. To developer unlock the phone, register your Microsoft Account on http://dev.windowsphone.com (paying the fee), download the SDK, and run the unlock tool.

If this is an enterprise app, you can also side-load the app by downloading it (via the web) and installing it. You will need to code sign the XAP first, and install the application enrolment token for this to work. See this post for more details: http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2012/12/03/Windows-Phone-8-SDK-Deploying-Multiple-Enterprise-Applications.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am a VS developer but wasn't really planning on becoming a Phone developer, definitely not just to be able to install someone else's app, was hoping there was an easier way (non-developer way). Thanks anyway

Answer (score -1):

You can freely register for [Windows Phone App Studio](http://apps.windowsstore.com/default.htm) and then developer unlock it for free.

More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769508).